# Updating parent Fragment from DialogFragment raises NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, fragmentmanager

I've struggled a while to update a `Fragment` from a `DialogFragment` after clicking the positive button. The `Fragment` is added programmatically to an `Activity`. When clicking the positive button in the dialog a NullPointerException raises, because the parent `Fragment` could not be found.
(I don't use `SupportFragments`.)

Any suggestions?

The parent `Activity`:

```
public class ResultActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.activity_result, ResultDetailsOneFragment.newInstance()).commit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The layout of 'ResultActivity':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_result"
    tools:context="com.myApp.view.ResultActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

The layout of 'ResultDetailsOneFragment':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_result_details_one"
    tools:context="com.myApp.view.ResultActivity$ResultDetailsOneFragment" >
    <!-- ... -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

The interface for the callback:

```
public interface EditResultDialogListener {
    void onDialogFinish();
}
```

The `DialogFragment`:

```
public class EditDescriptionDialog extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    protected void onDialogPositiveButtonClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        EditResultDialogListener resultDetailsOneFragment 
            = (EditResultDialogListener) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_result_details_one);

        /* here's the NullPointerException */
        resultDetailsOneFragment.onDialogFinish();
    }
}
```

Comment: i guess the dialog is invoked from the fragment?

Comment: Yes, it's invoked from the Fragment.

Comment: then you can pass a reference of the fragment to the dialog during invocation like in constructor and do your stuff, whats say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting nullpointer exception because you are trying to find the fragment inside the dialog fragment.

What you need to do is ->

Set the target fragment when showing the dialog ...

```
dialogFragment.setTargetFragment(ResultDetailsOneFragment.this, MY_REQUEST_CODE);
dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "tag");
```

Then in your onDialogPositiveClick,

```
@Override
protected void onDialogPositiveButtonClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // Send event back to parent fragment
    getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(MY_REQUEST_CODE, Activity.RESULT_OK, null);
}
```

So on dialog positive button click, the onActivityResult of your Fragment will be called.
Make sure you override the onActivityResult in your fragment class.

Comment: Any idea why after returning to the parent Fragment "getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_result_details_one);" returns null?